Why is Android localization not functioning properly on Android 14?
I am using two languages in my Android app, but when I switch languages, it doesn't work properly on Android 14. It works fine on lower versions
private fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String?): Boolean {
    val locale = language?.let { Locale(it) }
    Locale.setDefault(locale!!)
    val resources = context.resources
    val configuration = resources.configuration
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    
    return true
}

